# Reasons behind Java ConcurrentModificationException when using Collection.remove()

Tags: java, foreach, collections, iterator, concurrentmodification

Lots of contributions here on StackOverflow provide a clear explanation as to why one should use an Iterator and its remove method to get rid of an element of a collection while iterating it (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200489/collection-iterator-remove-vs-collection-remove), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re?rq=1), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602636/why-is-a-concurrentmodificationexception-thrown-and-how-to-debug-it)).

However, **what exactly causes** the `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown when one uses `Collection.remove()` instead of `Iterator.remove()`? I've been looking for a detailed answer but didn't find it. Even the The [Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html), simply states that:

> The for-each construct hides the iterator, so you cannot call remove.

What does this mean? How are the two implementations different and what is the chain of events that, in a piece of code like the one below, leads up to the exception?

```
Collection<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("Luke");
names.add("Leia");
names.add("Anakin");

for (String name : names) {
    if (name.equals("Anakin")) {
        names.remove(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `java.util.AbstractList` maintains internal field called `modCount`. It's incremented every time you modify this list. ArrayList's implementation of Iterator stores value of this field, and checks it every call to `next()`, and [throws an exception](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#L1040) when values don't match.

Comment: inside loop use 
names.remove(name.indexOf("Anakin")); in place of names.remove(name);
and make Collection as List bcz remove method not available in Collection
it present in List

Comment: @ImtiyazAhmad why not just do `names.remove("Anakin");` *instead* of the loop…

Comment: @Holger because in question he was trying to remove inside the loop so I did inside loop